# Clang ld failure in yocto build

Tags: clang, yocto, ld

While generating SDK for hardknott-based distro the following error occured from `clang_git.bb:do_compile()`:

```
qemux86-64/tmp-glibc/hosttools/ld: cannot find -ltinfo
qemux86-64/tmp-glibc/hosttools/ld: cannot find -lcurses
qemux86-64/tmp-glibc/hosttools/ld: cannot find -lncurses
qemux86-64/tmp-glibc/hosttools/ld: cannot find -lncursesw
```

I have already tried in `clang_git.bbappend` passing libraries to linker
`BUILD_LDFLAGS_append_class-nativesdk = "${path_where_libraries_are}"`
and making explicit dependency to ncurses `DEPENDS_append_append_class-nativesdk = " ncurses"`

How could the problem be mittigated?